# Map small surface onto larger surface in PyGame

Tags: python, mapping, pygame

I'm using PyGame's graphics library to display graphics on an LED display.

My LED display is 25x7. For testing without hardware, I've been able to use PyGame's `display` to view a 40x amplified version:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,280))
```

I'd like to actually draw boxes, rects, etc on a 25x7 grid and then project it onto a larger 1000x280 window on my computer, which will look like a 25x7 grid of 40x40 "pixels". That way, if I start working with hardware, I can skip the large projection, and just write 25x7=175 pixels worth of data out to my LEDs.

I came up with a solution, but it's prohibitively slow:

```
xDim = 25
yDim = 7

pixelMultiplier = 40
surf = pygame.Surface((xDim,yDim))
bigSurf = pygame.Surface((pixelMultiplier*xDim,pixelMultiplier*yDim))

# ... manipulate surf ...

# map surf to bigSurf
  for x in range(xDim):
    for y in range(yDim):
      # grab color of pixel
      tmpColor = surf.get_at((x,y))

      # write to all pixels in larger surface  
      for i in range(pixelMultiplier):
        for j in range(pixelMultiplier):
          bigSurf.set_at((pixelMultiplier*x+i,pixelMultiplier*y+j),tmpColor)
```

Is there some built-in PyGame function that does this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Right after writing the post, this dawned on me:

Create a surface to represent the pixel, and just `blit` that to the larger surface. Instead of running through 1600 `set_at()` functions for all 175 pixels, do it with a built-in function that already does that.

```
  # map surf to larger version
  for x in range(xDim):
    for y in range(yDim):
      # grab color of pixel
      tmpColor = surf.get_at((x,y))

      # create square surface to represent pixel
      pixelSurf = pygame.Surface((pixelMultiplier,pixelMultiplier))
      pixelSurf.fill(tmpColor)

      # blit big pixel onto bigSurf
      bigSurf.blit(pixelSurf,(pixelMultiplier*x,pixelMultiplier*y))
```

This runs *much* faster, but I'm still not sure it's the optimal solution.

**Edit - Best Method**

PyGame does have a built-in function!

```
pygame.transform.scale(surface,(newX,newY))
```